# how can mysql5 do the same thing just as oracle connect by prior order siblings by a field?

Tags: mysql, siblings

there are many ways to do the connect by prior with mysql5,
(I have known mysql8 support this query,however, I'm using mysql5),
I had known that I can use find_in_set to realize the connect by prior,
but how can I realize order siblings by just as oracle did.
for example,
here is the test data
e,my real data is that, the id is guid just like

```
62CF6FFEDE064B00ADFF43ED0E6EFDDB

create table test(id varchar(10),ordernumber decimal,pid varchar(10));
insert into test values('62CF6',2,'');
insert into test values('44DF8',3,'D13A3');
insert into test values('DD43F',5,'62CF6');
insert into test values('E7832',2,'53FAA');
insert into test values('48728',4,'D13A3');
insert into test values('53FAA',4,'62CF6');
insert into test values('9038A',1,'53FAA');
insert into test values('F5C7E',2,'D13A3');
insert into test values('D13A3',1,'');
```

in oracle  i can use

```
starts with pid is null connect by prior id=pid order siblings by ordernumber asd
```

to get this result

```
id     ordernumber  pid
D13A3     1    
F5C7E     2         D13A3
44DF8     3         D13A3
48728     4         D13A3
62CF6     2
53FAA     4         62CF6
9038A     1         53FAA
E7832     2         53FAA
DD43F     5         62CF6
```

since the level is unknown,I can only use the procedure like
just example code not real runnable.

```
create procedure test_p(in p varchar(100))
begin
declare aa varchar;
declare unit_cur cursor for select id from table where pid=p;
open unit_cur
fetch unit_cur into aa
call test_p(aa);
```

then if I have millions of tables to handle, how can i make only one procedure to the the similar thing?

Comment: pay attention to the order of the tree data

Comment: For MySQL 5.x the iterative stored procedure is the only option. Until special data - for example, only two levels of the relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY CASE WHEN pid = '' 
              THEN id 
              ELSE pid 
              END, 
         ordernumber;
```

---

> I had changed the data,my true id is guid – JokerSora

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.pid = t2.id
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t1.pid = ''
              THEN t1.ordernumber 
              ELSE t2.ordernumber 
              END, 
         t1.ordernumber;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e3c01067da653f7ae5ce5c969d0bd57f

Comment: I'm sorry that, when the id is not number, it doesn't work

Comment: @JokerSora What a problem? Convert to number. ```.. THEN id+0 ELSE pid+0 ...```.

Comment: I had changed the data,my true id is guid

Comment: I need the order by every group of tree with the ordernumber field,instead of the id and pid

Comment: if the level is not fixed?

Comment: @JokerSora If max. tree depth is known then build similar query which uses according amount of table copies. If not then read my comment to the question.

Comment: by your solution which use left join,when I need the starts with pid='D13A3',the sql is different with starts with pid=''. I need the solution of iterative query

Comment: e,so I can only use procedure to realize it? then I asked another question,How to make dynamice cursor using mysql5, here is my question ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72543031/the-cursor-of-mysql5-must-be-fixed-sql-sentence-how-can-i-realize-cursor-of-stri

Comment: I want to realize a procedure  by giving it a string of sql then it returns a result of iterative data,however,I'm not sure if mysql5 support the dynamice cursor of sql string just like oracle did

Comment: @JokerSora You do not need in cursor in SP. You'd use temporary table and fill it iteratively emulating recursive CTE. The value to be iteratively calculated is complete node `ordernumber` values path (with zero-padding), and this value'd be used in ORDER BY.